# Can't save checkout custom fields in database

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm able to add custom fields on checkout page and they are showing on checkout page now. However, the data entered into those fields is not saved into db after submitting the order.

I've followed below tutorial but still no luck.
https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

FYI, I'm using Mageplaza's Onestepcheckout module on my website.

Thanks in advance!